# PHP - imagejpeg() me imprime una imagen en blanco

Tags: php, imagen

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual basicamente toma la ruta de una imagen en `$payload` y despues la pasa a `imagecreatefromjpeg();` con la idea de en vez de desplegar un HTML con la etiqueta `<img src="">`, simplemente haga una salida de imagen.

En el siguiente codigo el problema que me surge es que la imagen se imprime o visualiza completamente en `blanco`, pero curiosamente las dimenciones (ancho y alto) de dicha imagen en blanco `si corresponden` a las dimenciones de la imagen. Ahora si esa imagen la sustituyo por otra de dimenciones 500x500, y refresco la pagina. Me imprime una imagen en blanco de 500x500. Porque? cual sera el problema? por donde puedo indagar ya que `el log no marca errores` de las funciones de imagen.

**IMPORTANTE:** Si, la imagen de la ruta si existe. Ya mire los Logs y NO hay informacion de error o que la libreria GD no este cargandose. Y buscando un poco mas, comente las todas las lineas e imprimi en una etiqueta  la ruta http + el contenido de `$payload` (ruta a la imagen), y SI me imprime la imagen real.

```
<?php
$payload= 'ruta/a/imagen.jpg';
header('Content-Type:image/jpg'); # cabecera imagen
$img= imagecreatefromjpeg($payload); # obtenemos imagen
imagejpeg($img); # imprimimos
imagedestroy($img); # liberamos buffer
?>
```

Comment: Prueba con el [ejemplo del manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#example-2927), deberías ver la imagen que especificas o una con texto de error.

Comment: Copie y pegue tu codigo, solo cambie la ruta y funciona perfecto, te lo dejo como ejemplo... [aca](https://jsfiddle.net/r5y0dLqs/)

Comment: Claramente es un problema de ruta o archivo, intenta como te he dejado y verás que sirve

Comment: @Triby he tomado el codigo del ejemplo del manual y me despliega una imagen en blanco tambien, aca donde tengo el codigo corriendo --> https://img.moneybox.business/almacen/qibg462n/1/r4

Comment: @Excorpion he revisado los permisos al las imagenes y estan bien. He quitado las funciones de imagen, colocado una etiqueta **<img src="">** y puedo ver perfectamente la imagen. Pero no me interesa verla en HTML, sino desplegarla directo como imagen :(

Comment: El enlace que enviaste parece tener una imagen pero le falta el encabezado correcto, probablemente te faltó la **e** en `Content-Type: image/jpeg`

Comment: @Triby es que he estado haciendole movimientos para ver si soluciono, pero nada.... de seguro entraste cuando estaba haciendo cambios !

Comment: Puede ser, ahora aparecen errores... https://gyazo.com/86f3e177282e9c8ae7ce82b301d793e4

Comment: Ya dejare de moverle... lo restaure como estaba el codigo, pueden probar !

Comment: *MIREN* que interesante... monte el codigo en un hosting publico y resulta el mismo problema, nada mas que aca el codigo imprime la RUTA y la respuesta al hacer GET por curl() a la ruta: https://img2.moneybox.business/almacen/qibg462n/1/r4

Comment: Podria alguien *probar* el siguiente codigo ?? --> https://pastebin.com/u5vUZ2FU

Comment: No logro ver la que montaste cuando dicen "miren".. el codigo se vee bien btw